# Circular Programming in Python (corecursion) - is it possible?

Tags: python

I know Python has some lazy implementations, and as such, I was wondering if it is possible to use circular programming in Python.

If it isn't, why?

Comment: [The Wikipedia page on Corecursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion) actually uses Python for code examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean co-routines, not co-recursion. Yes, it's perfectly possible in Python, since [PEP 342: Coroutines via Enhanced Generators](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) has been implemented.

The canonical example is the consumer decorator:

```
def consumer(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kw):
        gen = func(*args, **kw)
        next(gen)
        return gen
    wrapper.__name__ = func.__name__
    wrapper.__dict__ = func.__dict__
    wrapper.__doc__  = func.__doc__
    return wrapper
```

Using such `consumer` then let's you chain filters and push information through them, acting as a pipeline:

```
from itertools import product

@consumer
def thumbnail_pager(pagesize, thumbsize, destination):
    while True:
        page = new_image(pagesize)
        rows, columns = pagesize / thumbsize
        pending = False
        try:
            for row, column in product(range(rows), range(columns)):
                thumb = create_thumbnail((yield), thumbsize)
                page.write(
                    thumb, col * thumbsize.x, row * thumbsize.y
                )
                pending = True
        except GeneratorExit:
            # close() was called, so flush any pending output
            if pending:
                destination.send(page)

            # then close the downstream consumer, and exit
            destination.close()
            return
        else:
            # we finished a page full of thumbnails, so send it
            # downstream and keep on looping
            destination.send(page)

@consumer
def jpeg_writer(dirname):
    fileno = 1
    while True:
        filename = os.path.join(dirname,"page%04d.jpg" % fileno)
        write_jpeg((yield), filename)
        fileno += 1


# Put them together to make a function that makes thumbnail
# pages from a list of images and other parameters.      
#
def write_thumbnails(pagesize, thumbsize, images, output_dir):
    pipeline = thumbnail_pager(
        pagesize, thumbsize, jpeg_writer(output_dir)
    )

    for image in images:
        pipeline.send(image)

    pipeline.close()
```

The central principles are python [generators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), and [yield expressions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions); the latter lets a generator receive information from a caller.

**Edit**: Ah, [Co-recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion) is indeed a different concept. Note that the Wikipedia article *uses python* for it's examples, and moreover, uses python *generators*.

Comment: I thought that too, but it turned out, co-recusrion (a new term for me as well) is a different kind of thing and has nothing to do with coroutines.

Comment: @thg435: Ah, I see what you mean ([Corecursion on WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion)). Seems to me that generators and co-routines could be building blocks for that. In fact, the article examples *are written in Python*!

Comment: Reading over this answer, I came very near to down-voting it, but you did acknowledge that co-recursion is not necessarily isomorphic to co-routines. I think an actual co-recursive python implementation would be a object wrapping a coroutine, such that send calls into the coroutine, if of valid data would add some (element|value|property) to the objects underlying collection, i.e. it's __dict__, or something...

Comment: What exactly `thumb = create_thumbnail((yield), thumbsize)` is doing? Never saw `yield` as a function argument (of course in PEP doc)!

Comment: @haccks: `yield` is just another expression, one that produces a result (either `None` when itering, or whatever argument was given to `generator.send()`. It is the *result of the `yield` expression* that is passed to the function here. You could also use `item = yield`, then `thumb = create_thumbnail(item, thumbsize)`, to the same effect.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wow!. Never thought of using `yield` like this! Thanks for the explanation. I wrote a small code to understand it better: `def half(x):
    return x/2

def demystify_yield():
    while True:
        print(half((yield)))
dy_gen = demystify_yield()
next(dy_gen)
dy_gen.send(25)`
It works as expected. But I have a question here: shouldn't `print(half(yield))` legal as per the PEP doc? It throws an error of invalid syntax so I have to enclosed `yield` in an extra paren, `print(half((yield)))`.

Comment: @haccks the parentheses are [part of the `yield` expression syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/#new-syntax-yield-expressions) but can be omitted when it’s the sole expresion on the right-hand side of an assignment. IIRC the parentheses were needed to resolve operation precedence issues, but I don’t have any references right now so I could be wrong on that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the link above says `foo(yield)` and `foo(yield 42)` are legal. That's why I am confused.

Comment: @haccks: Ah! I see what you mean, the PEP example *is* confusing, as it directly contradicts the descriptive text above it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Just noticed what you said. "A yield-expression must always be **parenthesized except** when it occurs at the **top-level expression on the right-hand side of an assignment**". Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it?

```
def a(x):
    if x == 1: return
    print "a", x
    b(x - 1)

def b(x):
    if x == 1: return
    print "b", x
    a(x - 1)

a(10)
```

As a side note, python does not have tail recursion, and this will fail for `x > 1000` (although this limit is configurable)

Comment: these functions are tail recursive, so python has tail recursion;  it does not have **"tail call optimization"**

Comment: co-recursive != mutual recursive